# vb6 compile error 255

Tags: batch-file, vb6, compiler-errors, cruisecontrol.net

I have a batch file that I use with CruiseControl.NET to compile a vb6 project file. Frequently the build returns '255' as the ERRORLEVEL value. I am having difficulty trying to figure out what this error means.

Winerror.h gives some type of nebulous answer, but nothing really constructive and I am not even certain if the value represents a Winerror.h return code.

After the build errors out, I can successfully compile the vb6 project without recompiling any of our .NET code. Nothing else changes other than I am compiling directly from a batch file rather than being called through CCNET.

There is nothing very complex about the batch file code either. I just set a log file destination, make sure the previous file has been removed, create a new empty file, and then call vb6.exe /m %file% /out %logfile%

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try to resolve this problem. 
I probably get four or five failures per day. The only solution is to execute the batch file separately and then after it finishes I can successfully force the build. The next two builds may be successful after that and then a failure.

I wish at least it was consistent :D

Comment: Are you sure the bat file is even called? It could be that the bat file wasn't found. Your success builds may be because nothing has changed to force a recompile of the VB6 component. In the bat file, echo %date% to a file in a known location to see if it's really firing. When fails occur, has it compiled at all? Was it successful? Maybe you can ignore the 255 with an `exit /b 0` at the end of the bat

Comment: Good question. Yes, I am sure the batch file is called. It is a task in CCNET and it outputs a new logfile each time, which is generated by the batch file. Yes, I can ignore the error if I desired, but that is sort of dangerous if the vb6 project actually fails. I will try your suggestion of writing the date/time stamp to the file just to be sure that it has been called.

Comment: Find a job/company that doesn't use VB6.  Dude, that is just ev1l in 2014.

Comment: ha ha ha ... yeah, it is evil. They keep it because of the huge code debt it contains and the cost of converting.